# Workflow failing seconds after file upload

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 workflow associated with a document library which starts after a file is created. After running some tests I found out that the workflow works perfectly fine when I upload documents directly from Microsoft Word (via the ribbon button).

When I use the "upload document" option to load any kind of file to the library, it only works once. When I upload another file, the Workflow stops seconds after uploading it. If I restart the Workflow Management Site service on IIS it works again, but keeps failing at the second try.

Here's the error code if it helps:

> RequestorId: 1bad4f99-7894-cc54-0000-000000000000. Detalles: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 400
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["668"],"SPRequestGuid":["1bad4f99-7894-cc54-a988-e416cb4e5cf4"],"request-id":["1bad4f99-7894-cc54-a988-e416cb4e5cf4"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4420"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Wed,
>   20 Aug 2014 17:37:54
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.0"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>
> en
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)    en
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
>   en
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Answer (score 0):

Please check user profile of that particular user exist or not. If not try full user profile synch.

Still if your not able to get, use fiddler to verify that.
Usually , workflow picks from the UserInformationList which is hidden list using REST API's.

Also check if all timer jobs are running .